# For a complex number on the unit circle with irrational argument z, does $z^{N!}$ ever converge?

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-dynamics

Let $z = e^{2\pi i\alpha}$ with $\alpha \in [0, 1[$ irrational. I'm convinced the sequence $(z^{N!})_{N \in \mathbb{N}}$ has no reason to ever stabilize but I'm not sure how to prove or disprove this.

If we suppose it converges to 1 for example, then we know there exists $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N \ge M \implies d(z^{N!}, 1) < \frac{1}{2}$ and at the same time, the irrationality of $\alpha$ implies that there exists an infinite amount of natural numbers r such that $d(z^r, 1) \ge \frac{1}{2}$. This does seem like an absurd thing, but the problem is nothing forces those r's to be factorials, and so it could just happen that these two things don't contradict each other.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can stabilize, and in fact a handy example is $\alpha=e$!

Since $\displaystyle e=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k!}$, we have $\displaystyle N! e = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{N!}{k!} = M_N + \beta_N$
where $\displaystyle M_N = \sum_{k=0}^N \frac{N!}{k!}$ is an integer and $\displaystyle 0< \beta_N = \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{N!}{k!} < \frac2{N+1}$. And since $z^{N!} = e^{i(2\pi e N!)} = e^{2\pi i(M_N+\beta_N)} = e^{2\pi i\beta_N}$, we conclude that $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty} z^N = 1$ when $z=e^{2\pi ie}$.

Comment: I think $\alpha$ should be $e-2$. :)

Comment: according to the constraints in the OP, sure, but of course it matters not

Comment: In other words !
 approximates better and better integer numbers for large 
. Note that this is trivially the case also for (+)!
 where 
 is a rational number so the irrational numbers ∈(0,1)
 having the property that !
 approximates an integer for large n (in the sense that the distance from the closest integer goes to zero) is dense in (0,1). Maybe trivial as a follow up observation..
.